# Convert Date formats in base R

Tags: r, date

Given two dates in a data frame that are in this format:

```
 df <- tibble(date = c('25/05/95', '21/09/18'))
 df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
```

How can I convert the dates into this format - `date = c('1995-05-25', '2018-09-21')` with the year appearing first and in four digit format, and by only using base R?

Here is my attempt, I successfully reversed the order, but still wasn't able to express the year in 4 digit format:

```
df <- tibble(date_orig = c('25/05/1995', '21/09/2018'))
df$date <- as.Date(df$date_orig)
year_date <-  format(df$date, '%d')
month_date <- format(df$date, '%m')
day_date <- format(df$date, '%y')
df$newdate <- as.Date(paste(paste(year_date, month_date, sep = '-'), day_date, sep = '-'))
df$newdate_final <- as.Date(df$newdate, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know which format your date follows and find it in `?strptime` to convert it in date object. As you required output is the standard way to represent dates you would not need `format`.

```
as.Date(df$date, "%d/%m/%Y")
#[1] "1995-05-25" "2018-09-21"
```